# Trying to generate SSRS report based on input parameters in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have an AX query dataset that I'm trying to use to generate an SSRS report. I want to the user to be able to enter 2 parameters (Date and ProjectId) and have the SSRS report return a table based on the query using the parameters inputted by the user. Can't write any code so it needs to be purely graphical.

Comment: You will need to use the Filter tab on the table in the report. Set up the filter options to the params and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add your parameters to query as query ranges.

2. In the AOT, click Queries, and locate the query that you want to define a range for.
3. Expand the query, click Data Sources, and then expand a data source.
4. Right-click Ranges, and then click New Range.
5. Right-click the new range, click Properties, and then select a field in the Field property list.
6. Type an expression in the Value property to specify which records are retrieved.

here it's a helpful link for creating queries with ranges:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314753.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a walkthrough to follow:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc636713.aspx